# Call for multiple values to be displayed in textarea

Tags: javascript

I'm in the process of trying to create a simple input form web page using both HTML and JavaScript but I am stuck. What I am trying to do is to ask for the following and display them in the textarea:

```
-First Name
-Last Name
-CRN
-Professor Name
```

So far I am only able to get the First Name to show on the Results box but no luck with the other. Could use some help, thanks in advance.

My CODE looks like this:

```js
// initialize the counter and the array
var numbernames=0;
var names = new Array();
function SortNames() {

  // Get the name from the text field
  thename=document.theform["firstn"].value

  // Add the name to the array
  names[numbernames]=thename;

  // Increment the counter
  numbernames++;
  document.theform.sorted.value=names.join("\n");
  }
```

```html
<form name="theform">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstn" size="10" /><p>
  Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="lastn" size="10" /><p>
  CRN:
  <input type="text" name="crn" size="10" /><p>
  Professor:
  <input type="text" name="prof" size="10" />


  <input type="button" name="addname" value="Submit"
  onclick="SortNames();">
  <h2>Results:</h2>
  <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="sorted">
  </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, your JS is getting `theform["firstn"].value` but not getting the other fields, so ... ?

Comment: you really need to store the values in an array before set the textarea value?

Comment: Stephen, I understand it is getting firstn value, how can I make sure it gets the other values (last name, crn, professor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete different, but more readable approach.

1. I get all `inputs` of type text.
2. I get the `textarea` that is the target.
3. loop throug all inputs getting it's value.
4. inside loop, after getting the value, set it to the `textarea`

Take a look running the snippet below

```js
// initialize the counter and the array
function SortNames() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  var txtArea = document.querySelector('[name="sorted"]');

  //loop the text inputs
  inputs.forEach(function(elem){
    var valueOf = elem.value;
    txtArea.value += valueOf + '\n';  //concat the value
  });
  
}
```

```html
<form name="theform">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstn" size="10" /><p>
  Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="lastn" size="10" /><p>
  CRN:
  <input type="text" name="crn" size="10" /><p>
  Professor:
  <input type="text" name="prof" size="10" />


  <input type="button" name="addname" value="Submit" onclick="SortNames();">
  <h2>Results:</h2>
  <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="sorted"></textarea>
</form>
```

**EDIT**
If you REALLY want to keep the way you were doing, here's a solution:
1. Push the values from the inputs directly to the array, then set the value inside the textarea.

```js
// initialize the counter and the array
var names = new Array();

function SortNames() {
  names.push(document.theform["firstn"].value);    
  names.push(thename=document.theform["lastn"].value);
  names.push(thename=document.theform["crn"].value);
  names.push(thename=document.theform["prof"].value);
  document.theform.sorted.value=names.join("\n");
}
```

```html
<form name="theform">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstn" size="10" /><p>
  Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="lastn" size="10" /><p>
  CRN:
  <input type="text" name="crn" size="10" /><p>
  Professor:
  <input type="text" name="prof" size="10" />


  <input type="button" name="addname" value="Submit"
  onclick="SortNames();">
  <h2>Results:</h2>
  <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="sorted">
  </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: That works! But, since I am a complete beginner. Do you mind explaining how I can get the other values (last name, crn, professor) to show on the results box without changing much of the original code I provided.  Thank you

Comment: ok, i'll edit in a few minutes. But the way you where doing is much worse, not recommended... I suggest to learn more in the way I showed first. @AaronAguilar (ALREADY EDITED)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the tags to more *[semantic and functional tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)*. Used the [**HTMLFormControlsCollection API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) to set/get *[form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)*. The output is a [**Template Literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

**Details Commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
// Reference the top form
const reg = document.forms.registration;

// Reference the bottom form
const dis = document.forms.display;

// Collect all inputs from top form
const f = reg.elements;

// When top form is clicked...
reg.onclick = function(event) {

  // Collect the data from each input and store it in an Object
  const student = {
    First: f.first.value,
    Last: f.last.value,
    CRN: f.crn.value,
    Prof: f.prof.value
  };

  // Call function
  displayData(event, student);
}

function displayData(event, student) {

  // Reference the textarea
  const view = dis.elements.sorted;

  // if the element that was clicked had [name=add]...
  if (event.target.name === 'add') {

    /* Set the textarea's value to a Template Literal with
    || interpolated values from the student Object.
    */
    view.value += `
        First: ${student.First}
        Last.: ${student.Last}
        CRN..: ${student.CRN}
        Prof.: ${student.Prof}
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`;

    // Otherwise quit
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
input,
label {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  width: 20%
}

[type=text] {
  width: 75%;
}

[type=reset] {
  margin: 5px 0 0 85%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang=”en”>

<head>
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="registration">
    <fieldset id='set0'>
      <legend>Registration</legend>
      <label>First Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="first" size="10" /><br>

      <label>Last Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="last" size="10" /><br>

      <label>CRN: </label>
      <input type="text" name="crn" size="10" /><br>

      <label>Professor: </label>
      <input type="text" name="prof" size="10" /><br>


      <input type="reset" name="add" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <form id='display'>
    <fieldset id='set1'>
      <legend>View Data</legend>
      <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="sorted">
 </textarea>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```